# Pasting into a Word Bookmark without deleting the bookmark

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I've got a Microsoft Word project in Visual Studio and have some code that opens a seperate document and copies the text into the clipboard, then I'm just trying to paste that text into a bookmark in my main document.

If I use any of the Paste methods (`Paste`, `PasteAndFormat`, `.Range.PasteAndFormat`) it replaces the bookmark with the text.  If this was a once-off process then great but I still need that bookmark for further changes!  Effectively I want to keep adding text from all sorts of documents to the same bookmark, but if anyone can suggest a better way please let me know, thanks!!

```
var wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
object filename = "pathoffile";
var document = wordApp.Documents.Open(filename);
document.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
document.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();                

Globals.ThisDocument.bmTaskBreakDown.PasteAndFormat(WdRecoveryType.wdFormatSurroundingFormattingWithEmphasis);
```

Comment: unfortunately, it's common problem of using bookmarks. You need to: 1. remember starting point of bookmark, 2. add text into it (which remove the bookmark), 3. add the bookmark again from starting point + length of text you added... simple, but it requires additional snippet inside your code.

Comment: Thanks @KazJaw , annoying but OK, I'll have a go. You wouldn't have  some sample code for me?  Starting point I guess shouldn't be too hard but length of text added when it's pasted from clipboard?  Thanks!

Comment: I could search of vba code only... not sure if pasting from clipboard would work.

Comment: Thanks @KazJaw have you got any other ideas for bringing formatted text across from one word document to another?

Comment: copy+paste is the best :) copying into bookmarks and setting new bookmarks would work, I checked it in VBA. The other options- each part of the document belongs to collections, so you could use them (paragraphs, words, sentences). Next, each characters has it's position which you could be found (Range.End, Range.Start) and use to set new range (ActvieDocument.Range(_start, end_)... etc....

Comment: I've been avoiding understanding Ranges, guess I'll need to start readying.  Thanks, will report back when it's working!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace bookmarks content without removing the bookmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44926783/replace-bookmarks-content-without-removing-the-bookmark)