# Replace bookmarks content without removing the bookmark

Tags: c#, api, ms-word, office-interop

I want to replace the text content of bookmarks without loosing the bookmark.

```
foreach(Bookmark b in document.Bookmarks)
{
    b.Range.Text = "newtext";  // text is set in document but bookmark is gone
}
```

I tried to set the new Range of the bookmark before the Text setting but I still have the same problem.

I also tried to re-add the bookmark with `document.Bookmarks.Add(name, range);` but I can't create an instance of range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to readd the bookmarks and save the range temporarily. I also had to add a list of processed items to evade an endless loop.

```
List<string> bookmarksProcessed = new List<string>();

foreach (Bookmark b in document.Bookmarks)
{
    if (!bookmarksProcessed.Contains(b.Name))
    {
        string text = getTextFromBookmarkName(b.Name);
        var newend = b.Range.Start + text.Length;
        var name = b.Name;
        Range rng = b.Range;
        b.Range.Text = text;
        rng.End = newend;
        document.Bookmarks.Add(name, rng);
        bookmarksProcessed.Add(name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the above approach, you still lose the bookmark before it is added back in. If you really need to preserve the bookmark, I find that you can create an inner bookmark that wraps around the text (a bookmark within bookmark). After having the inner bookmark, you simply need to do:

```
innerBookmark.Range.Text = newText;
```

After the text replacing, the inner bookmark is gone and the outer bookmark is preserved.  No need to set `range.End`.

You can create the inner bookmark manually or programmatically depending on your situation.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it does exactly what is asked for!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you solved your problem, but here is a cleaner way to do it:

```
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

//declare and get the current document 
Document extendedDocument = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument);

List<string> bookmarksProcessed = new List<string>();  

foreach(Word.Bookmark oldBookmark in extendedDocument.Bookmarks)
{
    if(bookmarksProcessed.Contains(oldBookmark.Name))
    {
        string newText = getTextFromBookmarkName(oldBookmark.Name)

        Word.Range newRange = oldBookmark.Range;

        newRange.End = newText.Length;

        Word.Bookmark newBookmark = extendedDocument.Controls.AddBookmark(newRange, oldBookmark.Name);

        newBookmark.Text = newText;

        oldBookmark.Delete();
    }
}
```

Code isn't tested but should work.